# How to copy MP3 from PC to iPhone 4s without iTunes

Tags: itunes, iphone, mp3

How can I sync my MP3 collection on my Windows 7 PC with my iPhone 4S without having to use iTunes?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Tonido](http://www.tonido.com/support/display/docs/How+to+transfer+music+from+computer+to+iPhone+or+iPad+without+iTunes). I just tried it and it is really great (plus it support Windows, Mac, Linux and not only iPhone but also iPads, Blackberrys, Android and Windows Phones

Answer (score 2):

Here are two alternatives both for free:

For Windows: [SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com/download/)

For Mac: [DeTune](http://www.headlightsoft.com/detune/downloads.html)

Comment: All these software allow only to copy from device to pc. The question was the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of iTunes alternatives. Here are some links:

- http://www.copytrans.net
- http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/

Added explanation:

Both applications allow you to copy MP3s from your PC to your iPhone without using iTunes.  They are both commercial. Copytrans (19.99$) is available for Windows, while iExplorer (34.99$) has also a Mac download. And both apps have free test downloads.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. Thank you :)

Comment: You're right. I added some comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Google and Amazon double play to have access your music and sync and store locally certain tracks.

1. [Google Play](http://play.google.com/about/music/index.html), where you can upload 50,000 songs for free and access them all from a web browser, this works on iPhone, and there is a handy utility that you can install on your PC / Mac that will manage uploading to Google Play automatically. The only down side to Google play is that you must be connected to the internet to stream and play the music. Maybe at some point Google will release a Google Play Music app, but till then it does work in Safari.
2. Next for your must have offline tracks comes [Amazon cloud player](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/ref=sa_menu_mp3_ios1?ie=UTF8&docId=1000776061), which gives 5GB of storage free for personal music, aka stuff you did not purchase from Amazon MP3, more space is available for a yearly fee of 29.99.  With the Amazon could player iPhone App you can configure it to download your music stored in the Amazon Cloud Player for offline playing.

Answer (score 0):

This article is entitled [6 Ways To Sync Music To Your iPhone Without iTunes](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-to-sync-music-to-your-iphone-without-itunes/) published in Make Use Of. The article will explain:

- Media Monkey (Windows)
- Winamp and the ml_ipod plugin (Windows)
- SharePod (Windows)
- CopyTransManager (Windows)
- PwnPlayer (any platform)
- GtkPod (Linux Only - So N/A)

It should be beneficial to you.

Comment: I couldnt have really explained in any greater depth than I had already done so. The article explains in more detail & I didnt want to copy it word for word.

Comment: SharePod apparently (after some trying) only copies music FROM and not TO an iPhone/iPod :-(