# Transfer files from computer to iphone without using iTunes

Tags: data-transfer, file-transfer

Is there any way I can transfer files(songs) from my computer to my iPhone without using iTunes?

Comment: Can you expand a little on what you're trying to do?  Are you just wanting to use your device as a big flash drive or are you wanting access to the files on the device?  Also, what types of files are you referring to?

Comment: All of @kraymer's suggestions look like they may work for you but I'm still interested in what specifically you're trying to accomplish.  My initial thought is that contrary to what some of the articles below state, you can add any music you own, whether or not it was purchased from iTunes, to your iTunes library and for my money, it is the simplest and most effective way of syncing music to your iOS device, but I'm willing to bet that you have specific circumstances that make that not the case, otherwise you wouldn't be asking.  I'm curious what those are.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70975/how-to-copy-mp3-from-pc-to-iphone-4s-without-itunes/82559#82559

Comment: This question as written invites two answers. "Yes you can transfer songs without iTunes" and "No, you can not." Since it lacks details on OS, use case, what the OP has tried, let's close it to new answers until a more practical question can be phrased.

Answer (score 1):

Read [3 Ways to Transfer MP3 to iPod with or without iTunes](http://www.iskysoft.com/topic-ipod/how-to-transfer-mp3-to-ipod.html).

tldr :

- on Mac or Windows: [SyncPod](http://www.iskysoft.com/syncpod.html). But ...

  > This product currently is incompatible with Mac OS X Lion 10.7 or iOS 5.
- on Linux or Windows : [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/news/2012/09/24/ios-6-and-itunes-10-7-compatibility/)

  > Any version of MediaMonkey 4 can sync with any iPod, iPad, or iPhone
  >   (including the iPhone 5) via the following addon:
  >   http://www.mediamonkey.com/addons/browse/item/device-plugin-for-itunes/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what it is you are trying to do, but for starters I would suggest the Dropbox app.  With a free account, you can store up to 2 GB not only in the cloud but also on any device you use, including your iOS devices.  I find it to be a lot more streamlined than simply emailing myself stuff as well.

Comment: I already tried using dropbox. And yes it did helped me but not with songs.

Comment: So you're trying to add songs to your device without using iTunes but still be able to listen to those songs in the music app?

Comment: yeah that's what I want to do.

Comment: But why? You have a computer that presumably houses the music files, and you have sufficient admin access to install Dropbox so you could install iTunes if it isn't there already — are you just morally opposed to using iTunes, or is this just a "see if you can do it" kind of exercise?

Comment: If these are your own files, you can create a podcast containing the files.  Then set that podcast to download all and never expire.