# How can I copy my music from iPod Nano (model A1446) to iPhone 5s?

Tags: iphone, itunes, windows, ipod-nano

I am trying to somehow extract the music from my iPod and also transfer **all the playlists** the way I arranged them on the iPod before. The iPod is a 7th generation iPod Nano and I am using iTunes 12 on Windows.

It appears that the only option iTunes offers me that is obvious would be to wipe my iPod and then start synchronizing data from the PC to the iPod. This appears to be due to setting it to **manually manage music and videos** (see below). Effectively this would remove the data from the iPod and thus not leaving anything to copy to the iPhone.

[image]

Now I do know that I could transfer the files from iPod to PC in my file manager (`iPod_Control`). If I then import those files with their meaningless naming scheme iTunes will likely pick up all the song metadata. However, this won't aid me in any way in transferring the playlists over to the new device.

So how could I accomplish this without first wiping the iPod, then building an iTunes library from scratch, then transferring everything to both devices again?

Comment: see also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70975/how-to-copy-mp3-from-pc-to-iphone-4s-without-itunes

Comment: Is there something I do not understand? Does iTunes on a PC limit the devices you can sync with? On my Mac, I manage playlists in iTunes and then sync them to either my iPhone or my iPad, or both.

Comment: @patrix: not quite what I mean. In fact I want to "switch" from manual to automatic for the iPod and then use iTunes to transfer to the iPhone; while I always used iTunes to manage the songs on the iPod.

Comment: @iLikeStrongJava: it limits what it allows to sync with and makes it (more or less) a one-way. I.e. iTunes decides what it writes to the device. Problem is that the songs on my iPod are not in my iTunes library and never were (that's the effect of managing the music manually).

Comment: On mine, which I just tested, I can create playlists on the mobile device, and the next time I sync it shows up in my Library on the Mac, but I don't have a real complex library.

Comment: @iLikeStrongJava: do you have that **manually manage music and video** option checked? If so, how do you proceed to copy music off the device into your library? That'd be *the* answer I am looking for.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: True that. I don't have it checked (never felt I needed to). Have you consider turning that off? Of course, if you do try that, make sure you are convinced you can recover your music if the next sync wipes your iPod.  There is also an entry in the Apple Discussion groups that may be useful: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3991

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar problem. The only solution I found was an application called TouchCopy12. It allows you to transfer songs off of an iDevice directly to iTunes. I'm pretty sure you are able to transfer playlists as well. You get (I think) 82 transfers before you have to register. The link to the program, as well as information about it, will be located down below. I hope this helps and good luck!

http://www.wideanglesoftware.com/touchcopy/purchase.php

and

http://www.wideanglesoftware.com/touchcopy/features/index.php